# preventing value compilation errors

Tags: bixby

Bixby raises "Value Compilation Errors" in the debugger whenever I run a script that brings back Empty Optional Values.  The variable model is correct in that these values really are optional, i.e not needed for the user task to succeed.  So you can simply ignore the debugger errors and everything will work, EXCEPT that the Story testing tool will report these runs as "failed."  This means that the Story tool is almost useless for these cases, and that's a big problem.

Can someone show me how to code to avoid them?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a tip from @mincheng I finally figured out how to do this. The key is to delete any object properties that are null, undefined, or empty strings. I loop over my array of objects with the delete function.

```
  // remove undefined properties here

     const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
          if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') removeEmpty(obj[key]);
          else if (obj[key] === undefined || obj[key] === null || obj[key] === "") delete obj[key];
        });
        return obj;
      };


     for (var i = 0; i < altBrainsData.length; i++) {
           //console.log('i is', i);
           //console.log('function object', i, 'is', altBrainsData[i])
           //console.log(removeEmpty(altBrainsData[i]))
           altBrainsData[i] = removeEmpty(altBrainsData[i])
       }
```